# Are there any Grandmasters on this website?

Tags: discussion

I'm just curious about the number of Grandmaster available on this site

Just asking, answer if you are one

Comment: I don't think we have GMS, nor IMs at this site. I know we have few FIDE masters, but that is all we can offer for now... Again, this is what I know so far, so maybe I am wrong. This site is still in Beta stage, and has low traffic, so we need more time to "get" GMs to join. Also, it is hard to attract them because I don't see what kind of benefit they could get from answering questions for free, when they usually do this for the money :(

Answer (score 2):

The only instance of a GM using the site that I am aware of is [András Adorján](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A1s_Adorj%C3%A1n)'s post, appropriately enough, [about books specializing in play from Black's point of view](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/2612/167).

Answer (score 2):

Edit to better answer the question:

No active Grandmasters are on this site, as far as I know. Would be nice to have more titled players being active on this site.