# Actively encouraging titled players to use this site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, new-users

According to [this answer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/are-there-any-grandmasters-on-this-website/354#354), there is not even one grandmaster on Chess Stackexchange.

What a pity, especially when one considers the abundance of top experts and famous professors on e.g. Math Overflow.

My instinct is that there is a real opportunity to incorporate more, if not as much, expertise on this site.

**My proposal is that Stackexchange should take the initiative and get in touch with grandmasters and international masters. Invite them to join.** Those titled players who have academic backgrounds will be especially valuable.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your downvote

Comment: On meta, [downvotes may mean disagreement](/help/whats-meta) rather than a question being unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 4):

Grandmasters are the closest thing the chess world has to full time professionals. They are not going to waste time on something which doesn't have financial advantage for them and has very little to interest them.

StackExchange is not going to pay them to take part.

There is no real opportunity for them to gain paying students to coach via ChessSE.

Given the low level of the majority of the questions on ChessSE they are not going to be attracted by the content. Before people get over excited and protest, bear in mind that the majority of chess players are not very strong. Low level content is what they understand.